# add and remove class with jQuery on resizing

Tags: jquery, resize

I'am trying to add and remove class with jQuery while resizing window.

Code below is adding class "check", when view port width is lower than 919. But is not removing class when it becomes again more than 919.

Any ideas how to make it work?

```
$(window).on('load, resize', function mobileViewUpdate() {
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
if (viewportWidth < 919) {
        $('ul').addClass("check");
} else {
        $('ul').removeClass("ckeck");
}});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7kvs2b93/

Comment: Make the name the same in both places? Currently you have `check` and `ckeck`. Other than that, that code will definitely add/remove classes on every `ul` in the document on load and resize.

Comment: Better yet: Use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state): `$("ul").toggleClass("check", viewportWidth < 919);` Then you have less code and aren't repeating yourself (with the opportunity for error that that brings).

Comment: This code works, you just have a typo `$('ul').removeClass("ckeck")` i think you mean `$('ul').removeClass("check")`

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and other guys - thank you for your answers. It works.

Answer (score 0):

use Media Class instead of Jquery

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  ul {
    color:red;

  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nm0bgLL8/1/